# Continuity and Limits

Tags: limits, continuity

> Let  $f, g :\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuous such that given any two points $x_1\lt x_2$ there exists a point $x_3$ such that $x_1\lt x_3 \lt x_2$ and $f(x_3) = g(x_3)$. Show that $f(x) = g(x),\,\,\, \forall x\in\mathbb R.$

How do I go about this proof ? I had tried using sandwich theorem to show that the limits will coincide, but then realised that that won't work. Could somebody please help me out with this ?

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Take $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=2\sin x$, for any $x_1<x_2$ there is always a larger $x_3=2\pi n$ with $\sin x_3=2\sin x_3=0$.

Comment: $\sin$ and $\cos$ satisfy this. Don't you mean $x_1<x_3<x_2$ maybe?

Comment: yes you're right, I made a careless error. I'm very sorry, will edit the question right away. Could you please tell me how to prove this out ?

Comment: EdMo38, My prof had given this question in an assignment, I don't think the question is false.

Comment: Without loss of generality consider one function $h$ ($h=f-g$) which is continuous and $h(x_3)=0$ (I skip here the assumptions), show that $h\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that it is false. Then there is some $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0)\neq g(x_0)$. By continuity, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\bigl( \forall x\in(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon) \bigr):f(x)\neq g(x)$. Take $x_1=x_0-\frac\varepsilon2$ and $x_2=x_0+\frac\varepsilon2$. Then $x_1<x_2$, but there is no $x_3\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_3)=g(x_3)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $D:=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)=g(x)\}$.

Then $D$ is a [dense set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set).

The function $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)-g(x)$ is - as the sum two continuous functions - continuous and takes value $0$ on the dense set $D$.

Let $x\in\mathbb R$.

Since $D$ is dense  some sequence $(x_n)$ exists with $x_n\in D$ for all $n$ and $x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$.

Then $h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)=0$ since $h$ is continuous.

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again drhab. I haven't reached topology yet, so could you please provide a simpler answer ?. A hint would do, I'll try to work my way up from that.

Comment: Are the answers of José and/or Edmo38 on the right level for you? If so then just accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, so is $h$. Now, the condition gives for any $x_1<x_2$, there is an $x_3$ with $x_1<x_3<x_2$ such that $h(x_3)=0$. To prove that $h(x)\equiv 0$, take any $c\in\Bbb{R}$ and construct a sequence $y_i$ and $z_i$ with $y_i\to c$, $z_i\to c$ and $y_i<c<z_i$ for all $i$.

Now, your condition gives for all $i$ an $x_i$ with $y_i<x_i<z_i$ and $h(x_i)=0$. Clearly $x_i\to c$. Now we have an $x_i\to c$ with $h(x_i)=0$ for all $i$, which implies that $h(c)=0$, by continuity of $h$.

Since we picked $c$ arbitrarily, $h(c)=0$ for all $c\in\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: EdMo38, if I take $\ y_i$ = -1/x and $\ z_i$= 1/x would this work ?. Is the sequence that's constructed fine ?.

Comment: Not sure that will work. What is $x$? Where is $c$? 

If we've picked a $c$, we could use $y_i=c-1/i$ and $z_i=c+1/i$, this way we have $$y_i=c-1/i<c<c+1/i=z_i.$$
This way each $x_i$ will be between $c-1/i$ and $c+1/i$, so $x_i\to c$.